# Swift: CGPathRelease and ARC

Tags: ios, memory-management, swift, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

Just updated to Xcode Beta 4, and noticed the following compiler error with my code below:

```
var path = CGPathCreateMutable()
...
CGPathRelease(path)
```

> 'CGPathRelease' is unavailable: Core Foundation objects are
>   automatically memory managed

So do I simply just remove my release calls and everything should be fine? Or is there something more I'm missing? And are there any special cases I should be aware of with ARC?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) section of *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C* says (emphasis mine):

> Core Foundation objects returned from annotated APIs are automatically memory managed in Swift—**you do not need to invoke the `CFRetain`, `CFRelease`, or `CFAutorelease` functions yourself**. If you return Core Foundation objects from your own C functions and Objective-C methods, **annotate them** with either `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED` or `CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED`.
>
> …
>
> When Swift imports APIs that have not been annotated, the compiler **cannot** automatically memory manage the returned Core Foundation objects. Swift wraps these returned Core Foundation objects in an **`Unmanaged<T>` structure**.

So yes, unless you have an `Unmanaged` struct, this is correct and you don't have to worry about manually releasing the object.

Comment: @jtbandes How does one determine is a CF function is annotated?

Comment: @Zaph Check the definition of the function in the C header for `CF_RETURNS_...`, or the Swift header for `Unmanaged`, as mentioned in the guide.

Comment: There is no mention of `Unmanaged` in the Swift Programming Guide.

Comment: The quote I posted in my answer, and the link I posted in my answer, should contain all the necessary information.

Comment: @Zaph As @jtbandes linked, `Unmanaged<T>` is described in the _Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C_ programming guide, not in _The Swift Programming Language_.